# The value True (type bool) in a string field was converted to u'True' (type string)

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to follow [parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#parameters)/[examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#examples), yet running into following WARNING message while executing Ansible'playbook:

```
TASK [apt (pre)] ********************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: The value True (type bool) in a string field was converted to u'True' (type string). If this does
not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.
```

relevant part of playbook:

```
- name: apt (pre)
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    upgrade: yes
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to recreate your results.

What I found is `upgrade` is expecting a string value.  In addition to `yes` and `no` you can use `dist`, `full`, or  `safe`

Changing your playbook to the following should achieve the desired results:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
          - name: apt (pre)
            apt:
                update_cache: yes
                upgrade: 'yes'
```

**Reference**

[Ansible Apt Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html)